# Undoing at Lightroom: Ctrl+Z vs. History

Tags: lightroom, workflow

I've found a different behaviour when these methods are applied.

Ctrl+Z restores deleted (forward) history states if your last action was to go back in history, and also is able to undo the selection of a given history state.

However, sometimes one would prefer to go back a step in history. Is there a shortcut for that?

Comment: Are you asking for a keyboard shortcut like **Ctrl+Z** to go move to and fro in the history panel or the difference between Undo and what is in the History Panel?

Comment: Both things, indeed. Further differences plus shortcuts for navigating through history entries.

Answer (score 1):

**Undo** as everyone knows, is to go back any number of steps backwards, so that you can remove the previous action, and go to the previous state. (Shortcut is *Ctrl+Z*)

In *Lightroom*, there is a feature called **History**, which displays all the modifications, effects you used on a particular image. One great thing about *History* panel in *Lightroom* is that the entries will not get erased, but will be available even when you close *Lightroom* and open another window. The *History* panel displays the details of the changes you did. You can click on a particular entry and click on it and the image will go that state, removing all the changes to the image (but of course you can go to the latest changes, again by clicking on the latest entry). But if you make changes after going back to an earlier entry, you will lose the entries (changes) you did after that. You can expand and collapse the *History* panel by using *Ctrl + Shift + 3* combination, and then move using arrow keys along the entries.

Comment: Also, Ctrl+Z can recover "forward" erased states.

Comment: I still would love having a shortcut for "step back" in history, as well as being able to batch apply that or to configure a preset with that command. Now I am interested in a workaround for automatically hiding the preview of a set of images ([as discussed here](https://feedback.photoshop.com/conversations/lightroom-classic/lightroom-classic-ability-to-hide-sensitive-photos/5f5f452b4b561a3d42393bc5?commentId=5f9428ff35f40c3a18c90f2d&replyId=601ae0bd1dbf513517cb5c8e)).